# How to write named native subqueries in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I was given a task to write a named native subquery like

```
select c.comp_name from company c where c.cid = (select cid from com_usr_rel where uid=1100)
```

The entities are

**company**

```
@Entity

public class Company implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="company_id")
private String companyId;

@Column(name="apartment_no")
private BigDecimal apartmentNo;

private String city;

@Column(name="company_name")
private String companyName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to CompanyUser
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
private List<CompanyUser> companyUsers;

public Company() {
}

public String getCompanyId() {
return this.companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
this.companyId = companyId;
}

public BigDecimal getApartmentNo() {
return this.apartmentNo;
}

public void setApartmentNo(BigDecimal apartmentNo) {
this.apartmentNo = apartmentNo;
}

public String getCity() {
return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
return this.companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
this.companyName = companyName;
}

public List<CompanyUser> getCompanyUsers() {
return this.companyUsers;
}

public void setCompanyUsers(List<CompanyUser> companyUsers) {
this.companyUsers = companyUsers;
}}
```

**com_usr_rel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="com_usr_rel")
public class CompanyUser implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="com_usr_rel_id")
private String comUserId;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Company
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="company_id")
private Company company;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to User
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;

public CompanyUser() {
}

public String getCom_usr_relId() {
return this.comUserId;
}

public void setCom_usr_relId(String com_usr_relId) {
this.comUserId = comUserId;
}

public Company getCompany() {
return this.company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
this.company = company;
}

public User getUser() {
return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
this.user = user;
}
}
```

@Update
OOPS.

The Named Native query does not execute. It gives me an exception saying that Native Scalar queries are not supported.

```
org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported
```

@Update

Solved it by using relationship in the entities.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Does the native query that you posted not work? Are you asking how to specify the @NativeNamedQuery annotation? ...? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this [doesn't work](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4412) on Hibernate